# How to add a new element to the numbered array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add a new element to the numbered array, which already has elements in it. One element added, but if I try to add the next one it only replace existed one.

```
$arr = mixOfArray($arr_assoc_woman);
if(in_array($userName, $arr_assoc_man)) {
    $rand = array_rand($arr, 1);
    echo "<p class='css3-blink'>$userName + $arr_assoc_woman[$rand] = Happy Couple!</p>";
} else {        
    $numb = count($arr_assoc_man);
    print($numb);
    $arr_assoc_man[$numb] = $userName;
    $arr_assoc_man += $arr_assoc_man;
    $arr = mixOfArray($arr_assoc_woman);
    $rand = array_rand($arr, 1);
    echo "<p class='css3-blink'>$userName + $arr_assoc_woman[$rand] = Happy Couple!  </p>";
}
```

Comment: You're trying to append an element to the array with `$arr_assoc_man[$numb]`? It is almost never necessary to specify an array key when appending to a numeric-indexed array. Instead use the `[]` syntax: `$arr_assoc_man[] = $userName;` There's no need to get the current `count()` of elements or worry about the keys.

Comment: ^^ Here are the relevant docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to append an element to the array with     $arr_assoc_man[$numb]. I already change     $arr_assoc_man[$numb] = $userName;  to     $arr_assoc_man[] = $userName;  
But it works in the same way.
Can you advice me how to make my code in the comment to look like code in your comment?

Comment: Is your code part of a function? The only instance I can think of where it would keep writing to the same element is if you are passing the array to a function and not returning it, so it stays the same _outside_ the function. Please post a little more code for context, as well as the definition of the `mixOfArray()` function.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. I should use a session to store my array in it and use the current instanse for it. In other way it always will be a reinitialisation.

Answer (score 1):

try using `[]` instead of your define key if it's auto numbering.

replace `$arr_assoc_man[$numb]` to `$arr_assoc_man[]`

Answer (score 0):

you are using an indexed array.In indexed array php numbers each array element automatically, beginning from 0 (first element of an array) upto number of elements. To add a new element to the end of the array, use a pair of empty
square brackets like this:
$arr_assoc_woman[] = "$value";
php uses the next available number, so this becomes $arr_assoc_woman[(here is the number assigned by php)].

Answer (score 0):

To add an extra element to the current array you can use array_push() function.

```
<?php
    $stack = array("orange", "banana");
    array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");

    print_r($stack);
?>
```